# Django models or view

Tags: django

Коллеги прошу помощи! Есть две модели question и answer. Надо чтобы к question создавалось несколько answer один верный и два три неверных. Как в тесте. Как сделать? Делать модель неверного ответа или это во view собирать?

Answer (score 0):

Думаю можно двумя вариантами:

1. в модели `asnwer` добавить поле `is_true` значение которого будет `true`, если ответ верный, и `false`, если не верный.
2. в модели `question` добавить поле `true_answer` содержащее правильный ответ.